# syscall or gettid system function from Cython

Tags: linux, cython

I need to call `gettid` from Cython. Accordingly to its man page, I should use the `syscall` function. I'm running Linux.

I can easily get the `gettid` function number:

```
cdef extern from "sys/syscall.h":
    cdef int __NR_gettid
```

But I cannot find how to import, or better cimport, `syscall`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up in the cython's github repository, how those includes are done best, for example: [stdio.h](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/stdio.pxd).

Applying this leads to:

```
%%cython
cdef extern from "<sys/syscall.h>" nogil:
    int __NR_gettid
    long syscall(long number, ...)

def gettid():
    return syscall(__NR_gettid)
```

And now `gettid()` yields:

```
>>> gettid()
7231
```